# How to do zoom in ScrollPane

Tags: java, libgdx

I've got problem with setting up zoom efect in my game. So i have `Stage` object which is filled by `ScrollPane`, which includes `Table` with couple `Actor's`. I want it to be possible to zoom in and zoom out elements of that Table using gestures (and scrollbars adjust to its new size). I've tried with `stage.getCamera().zoom` however it changes size of whole ScrollPane which i don't want to. I came up with the idea of changing size of all actors of that Table however I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do that is, like you said, changing the size of the table in scrollpane. I actually ended up extending the stack and changing scale of the table in the stack, and then i had another table for actual size. I needed that for my app:

```
public ZoomableStack() {
    imageTable = new Table();
    sizeTable = new Table();

    this.add(imageTable);
    this.add(sizeTable);

    layout();

    imageTable.setTransform(true);
}
```

Get the scaled sizes for the table:

```
@Override
public float getPrefWidth() {
    return imageTable.getWidth() * imageTable.getScaleX();
}

@Override
public float getPrefHeight() {
    return imageTable.getHeight() * imageTable.getScaleY();
}
```

Override layout method like so:

```
@Override
public void layout() {
    float width = this.getWidth();
    float height = this.getHeight();

    imageTable.setSize(imageTable.getPrefWidth(), imageTable.getPrefHeight());

    float tableWidth = imageTable.getWidth();
    float tableHeight = imageTable.getHeight();

    imageTable.setOrigin(tableWidth / 2, tableHeight / 2);
    imageTable.setPosition((width / 2 - (tableWidth / 2)), (height / 2 - (tableHeight / 2)));
    sizeTable.setBounds(((width - getPrefWidth()) / 2), ((height - getPrefHeight()) / 2), getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());
}
```

You may need to override setCullingArea() because the table will end up bigger than screen, and then all your actors in the table will disappear:

```
@Override
public void setCullingArea(Rectangle cullingArea) {

}
```

Then create zoom method where you call invalidateHierarchy():

```
public void zoom(float amount) {
    imageTable.scaleBy(amount);
    invalidateHierarchy();
}
```

Then you just add the stack in to your scrollpane and use the zoom:

```
ZoomableStack zoomableStack = new ZoomableStack();
new ScrollPane(zoomableStack);

zoomableStack.zoom(speed * amount);
```

Comment: Great solution!